# import error No module named 'project\\order'

Tags: django, importerror, django-oscar

I'm using oscar and added from fork order app. After added that cant run syncdb or server. It is giving an error import error: No module named 'project\\order'

```
from oscar import get_core_apps
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'compressor',
] + get_core_apps(['project\order'])

SITE_ID = 1
```

this is my installed apps. I didnt understand why it doing this.

Comment: does the project order has a file called __init__

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer yes it has

Comment: What does your project directory structure look like?

Comment: Oscar
Db.sqlite3
Manage.py
-include
-lib
-project 
İnit.py
Settings
Urls.
wsgi
-__pycache__
-order

-public
-scripts

Comment: order and pycache are in project

Answer (score 0):

This `get_core_apps(['project\order'])` should be `get_core_apps(['project.order'])`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed project to oscar.apps.order and it did work. But why, it is a question for me.